# how to perform mathematical operations on numbers in a file using perl or awk?

Tags: text-processing, awk, perl

I have a fileA.txt:

```
RS0255_RS0083:115,124,129,141,143,168,170,180
RS0343_RS0083:112,113,163,175,181
RS0343_RS0255:94,101,107,164,179,183
```

I would like to perform mathematical operations on the numbers after :
For example, I want to add 10 to each number:
Output:

```
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

I know how to do it in R but how to do this mathematical operation on numbers in a file in `perl` or `awk`?

Comment: "_in linux_" doesn't really make sense. What programming language do you want to use? `python`? `perl`? `awk`? `C`? `Go`? `Ruby`? Something else?

Comment: I am afraid this is way too broad. There are dozens of tools that can be used but it depends on exactly what you need.

Comment: yeah I meant perl or awk, sorry

Comment: Related: [Increment numbers greater than 50 in a file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/632382)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are quite literally dozens of tools you can use for different manipulation of text files. For the specific case you mention, I would probably use perl:

```
$ perl -pe 's/\b(\d+)\b/$1 + 10/ge' fileA.txt 
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

Comment: I tried multiplication, addition and subtraction, all ok, for the division how to do? let's suppose I want divide by 10?

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini, I'd use a different delimiter for `s/pattern/repl/flags` like `s:pattern:repl:flags` or `s{pattern}{repl}flags`

Comment: @PaoloLorenzini The  division operator (`/`) happens to be equal to the delimiter used in the substitute perl command (`s/.../.../`). To be able to to use that symbol in the replacement part, either change the delimiter (`s#...#...#`) or escape the character (`\/`). Either `perl -pe 's#\b(\d+)\b#$1/10#ge' file` or `perl -pe 's/\b(\d+)\b/$1\/10/ge' file`

Answer (score 8):

```
gawk '$0+0 == $0 {$0 += 10} {ORS = RT} 1' RS='[:,\n]' file
```

Answer (score 7):

An `awk` answer:  Parse each line as two `:`-delimited fields. Use `split()` on the second field to split it into fields on the commas, and modify the split-up fields in a loop, creating a new output record. Then output the new record with commas as delimiters, and with the original first field as a "prefix".

```bsh
awk -F : '
    BEGIN { OFS = "," }
    {
        prefix = $1
        nf = split($2,a,",")
        $0 = ""

        for (i = 1; i <= nf; ++i)
            $i = a[i] + 10

        printf "%s:%s\n", prefix, $0
    }' fileA.txt
```

The output would be

```
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

More compact presentation of the above code (for those of you that thinks one-lines are somehow "better"):

```
awk -F: '{p=$1;n=split($2,a,",");$0="";for(i=1;i<n;++i)$i=a[i]+10;printf "%s:%s\n",p,$0}' OFS=, fileA.txt
```

---

Older answer, which is not as "nice" as the above one:

Using `awk` and interpreting each line as a list of fields delimited by `:` or `,`, adding 10 to the 2nd field onward on each line:

```bsh
awk -F '[:,]' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) $i += 10 }; 1' fileA.txt
```

This would give you

```
RS0255_RS0083,125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083,122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255,104,111,117,174,189,193
```

To change the first comma on each line back to a `:`, use `sed 's/,/:/'`:

```bsh
awk -F '[:,]' 'BEGIN { OFS="," } { for (i = 2; i <= NF; ++i) $i += 10 }; 1' fileA.txt |
sed 's/,/:/'
```

Answer (score 5):

```
awk -F, -v OFS=, '{
    split($1, tmp, ":");
    $1=tmp[1] ":" tmp[2]+10;
    for(i=2; i<=NF; i++ ) $i+=10;
}1' infile
```

Answer (score 4):

I propose this `awk`:

```bsh
$ awk -F':|,' 'BEGIN { OFS="" } 
    $1 = $1":" { 
      OFS=""; 
      for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) { 
        $i = $i + 10; 
        if ( i != NF ) { 
          $i = $i"," 
        } 
      }; 
    }1' file
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

Answer (score 3):

Using **awk**
with a progressive slicing around comma we recreate fields dynamically.

```
awk -F: -v OFS=, '
{
  f1=$1 FS; f2=$2 OFS
  n=0; $0=""
  while (p=index(f2, OFS)) {
    $(++n) = 10 + substr(f2,1,p-1) 
    f2 = substr(f2, p+1)
  }
  $1=f1 $1
}1
' fileA.txt
```

**Output:**

```
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

---

```
perl -pe '/:/g;
  s/\G(\d+)(\D)/($1+10).$2/ge;
'fileA.txt 

#alternatively 
perl -ne '
  print !$|-- ? $_ : s/\d+/$&+10/reg
     for /(.*:)(.*)/s;
' fileA.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```
raku -pe 's:g/ <[:,]> <(\d+)> /{$/.Num + 10}/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
RS0255_RS0083:115,124,129,141,143,168,170,180
RS0343_RS0083:112,113,163,175,181
RS0343_RS0255:94,101,107,164,179,183
```

Sample Output:

```
RS0255_RS0083:125,134,139,151,153,178,180,190
RS0343_RS0083:122,123,173,185,191
RS0343_RS0255:104,111,117,174,189,193
```

In this case I think I'd reach for Raku (Perl5's kid sister), for reasons including robust handling of numerics. Briefly, a global `s:global///` substitution is performed above and autoprinted using the `-pe` command line flag. The regex searches for digits following either a `:` colon or a `,` comma. The match outside the digits is dropped outside the `<(...)>` markers. In the replacement, the `$/` variable is coerced to `.Num` and 10 is added.

*[Note: You'll have to do a little more work to handle decimal points and/or numbers-containing-commas].*

FYI, you can do some really nice (readable) things with `Rationals`. Here's an example:

```
raku -pe 's:g/ <:Nd + [\c[FULL STOP]]>+ /{$/.Rat.numerator}\/{$/.Rat.denominator}/;'
```

Sample Input:

```
 3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 21, 24
 4, 8, 12, 16, 20
 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 3.0
 0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1.0, 1.25, 1.5
 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1.0, 1.2, 1.4, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0
```

Sample Output:

```
 3/1, 6/1, 9/1, 12/1, 15/1, 18/1, 21/1, 24/1
 4/1, 8/1, 12/1, 16/1, 20/1
 1/2, 1/1, 3/2, 2/1, 5/2, 3/1
 1/4, 1/2, 3/4, 1/1, 5/4, 3/2
 1/5, 2/5, 3/5, 4/5, 1/1, 6/5, 7/5, 8/5, 9/5, 2/1
```

https://docs.raku.org/type/Rational
https://raku.org/